# SUMIFS with multiple criteria and OR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, criteria, sumifs

I have seen plenty of posts for SUMIFS with or, but all the examples have a single criteria and an OR. This is usually done with an array like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"red","blue"}))
```

I need to be able to do that, but I need it to have multiple AND criteria and the OR using array or something similar
Like this:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range1,criteria1,criteria_range2,{"red","blue"}))
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Help please!

Comment: Does it work as an array formula (finalizing with [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter] rather than [enter])?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it doesn't.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve]. As it stands right now, your question is too vague to provide specific help.

Comment: Further, '*it doesn't seem to work*' is not a valid error code or error description.

Comment: {=SUM(SUMIFS('Data'!$AH$3:$AH$1048576,'Data'!$I$3:$I$1048576,$C7,'Data'!$AX$3:$AX$1048576,"",'Data'!$BK$3:$BK$1048576,{"Less","Between"}))}

Where:
AH has the values I want to sum from the Data page.
I only want to sum where the values in AX on the data page match C7 on the current sheet
and where the values in BK on the data page = "Less" or "Between" on the Data page

Comment: Your formula and you last comment do not match. You are testing `C7` against column `I` and then column `AX` for empty. There is no problem for the way you are testing against an array.

Comment: Could you visit [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and ask for an update to the [mcve] page explaining why that was unclear to you?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for. Where do the `OR` stands in your formula? what have you tried so far?  Kindly read formatting help: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

I'm showing you how it works with an example

Have the following table starting in A1:

```
a|0|1
a|1|2
b|0|1
b|1|2
b|0|1
c|0|1
c|0|1
```

Then you try this to sum values in the third column (C) where first column (A) is either "a" or "b" (result is 7):

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C7, A1:A7, {"a","b"}))
```

Then try this to sum values in the third column (C) where first column (A) is either "a" or "b" AND the value in second column (B) is 0 (result is 3):

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(C1:C7, B1:B7, 0, A1:A7, {"a","b"}))
```

Note that since these formulas contain an array, they are already array formulas. You don't need to force an array formula by using [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter].

Comment: Thank you, Fran. Solved!

Comment: Tou're welcome @Bilk0. If the answer works, you can click the arrow on the upper left of it to 'accept it' :)