# SUMIFS with mutliple OR/AND criterias (using a cell reference)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
      A             B              C            D               E            F          G        E
1  Products     Suppliers        Value     Criteria 1:     Product_C      Result:      600
2  Product_A    Supplier_01      500       Criteria 2:     Supplier_01      
3  Product_B    Supplier_01      600       Criteria 3:     Supplier_03  
4  Product_B    Supplier_02      300                
5  Product_C    Supplier_01      200                
6  Product_C    Supplier_01      400                
7  Product_C    Supplier_03      800    
8
9
```

In the table you find a list of different `Products` (`Column A`) and `Suppliers` (`Column B`).

In `Cell G1` I want to get the `sum` of the values in `Column C` if the following conditions are met:

Product = `Product_C` **AND** 
Supplier = `Supplier_01` **OR** `Supplier_03`

Those conditions are typed in as `Criteria 1-3` in `Cells E1:E3`.

In order to achieve this I tried to go with the solution from these questions ([Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528616/sumif-with-or-criteria),[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44525609/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or)) which gives me the correct result:

```
G1 =SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E$1,$B:$B,{"Supplier_01","Supplier_02"}))
```

---

However, my issue with this solution is that I need to enter the `OR-criterias` manually as `{"Supplier_01","Supplier_02"}`. 
 How do I have to change my formula so I can refer to the values in `Cells E2:E3` so if the user changes those values the result is automatically adjusted?

Comment: Are you willing to use column **D** as a "helper" column ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A7=E1)*((B2:B7=E2)+(B2:B7=E3))*C2:C7)
```

It will be easy to extend criteria in the same fashion for both column A and B.

Comment: It worked, but I had transpose in originally and realised it was unnecessary in the particular example that OP gave.

Comment: Another way of solving the issue can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61894421/add-if-condition-to-sumproduct

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say that you need to transpose E2:E3. I think this is true in general, but in this particular case with only a single criterion applying to column A, you don't need to:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E$1,$B:$B,$E$2:$E$3))
```

works if entered as an array formula.

If you have multiple criteria for  A and B, you do need to transpose one set of criteria:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E$1:$E$2,$B:$B,TRANSPOSE($E$3:$E$4)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E$1,$B:$B,E2:E3))
```

or

```
=SUM(IF(($A$2:$A$7=E1)*(($B$2:$B$7=E2)+($B$2:$B$7=E3)),$C$2:$C$7,0))
```

Comment: Looks like a one-on-one copy of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61170940/9758194) =)

Comment: As I forgot to refresh the page before presenting the answer, so I added another formula for ref. @Jvdv   And I think your formula is the best, very simple.