# Add IF-Condition to SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
       A           B            C             D           E            F         G       H    
1  Products       Date        Sales     Criteria 1:   Product_B      Result:    200
2  Product_A    2020-04-15     500      Criteria 2:   2020-04-15    
3  Product_B    2020-04-12     600              
4  Product_B    2020-04-12     300              
5  Product_B    2020-04-15     200              
6  Product_B    2020-04-20     400              
7  Product_C    2020-04-15     800              
8  Product_C    2020-04-19     900              
9  Product_C    2020-04-30     300              
10
11
```

In the table above I have different products and their sales on a certain date. 
In `Cell G1` I calculate sum of the sales based on the criterias in `Cell E1` and `E2`.

```
G1 = SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$100=$E$2)*$C$2:$C$100))
```

All this works exactly as it should.

---

Now, I want to include an `IF-Condition` that says if you enter the words `"All Products"` into `Cell E1` the product condition `($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)` in the `SUMPRODUCT` should **not be applied**.

Therefore, I tried to go with this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((IF(E1="All Products",1,($A$2:$A$100=$E$1))*($B$2:$B$100=($E$2))*$C$2:$C$100))
```

Unfortunately, this solution only works if I enter `"All Products"` into `Cell E1`. 
Once I switch back to `Product_B` it displays `0` instead of `200`.

What do I need to change to make it work?

---

**NOTE:**

I know one solution could be to split the `SUMPRODUCT` into two formulas like this:

```
=IF(E1="All Products",SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B$100=$E$2)*$C$2:$C$100)),SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)*($B$2:$B$100=$E$2)*$C$2:$C$100)))
```

However, I would prefer a solution with one `SUMPRODUCT`-Formula.

Comment: Why not just use `SUMIFS`? This would be pretty easy with a nested `IF` and a wildcard.

Comment: Only works as long as I don't want to add OR-Criterias: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170789/sumifs-with-mutliple-or-and-criterias-using-a-cell-reference

Comment: @Michi did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode to make it an array formula?

Comment: @Michi sumifs will work with or, from your last question with this: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,IF(E1="All Products","*",$E$1),$B:$B,$E$2:$E$3))` no CSE needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,IF(E1="All Products","*",$E$1),$B:$B,$E$2))
```

[image]

---

Combining with your [LAST QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61170789/sumifs-with-mutliple-or-and-criterias-using-a-cell-reference)

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,IF(E1="All Products","*",$E$1),$B:$B,$E$2:$E$3))
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Modify the column **A** criteria as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($A$2:$A$100=$E$1)+($E$1="All Products")*($A$2:$A$100=$A$2:$A$100))*($B$2:$B$100=$E$2)*$C$2:$C$100)
```

The new factor `+($E$1="All Products")*($A$2:$A$100=$A$2:$A$100)`  will ensure a vector of all **1** with the appropriate input in **E1**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Array (Control+Shift+Enter) formula in F2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF((E1<>"All Products"),(A2:A9=E1),TRUE)*(B2:B9=E2)*(C2:C9))
```

[image]

Following Array formula is better than the above one. If you enter anything that doesn't match in column A it will consider it as "All Products"

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(COUNTIF(A2:A9,E1)=0,TRUE,(A2:A9=E1))*(B2:B9=E2)*(C2:C9))
```

OR

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNA(MATCH(E1,A2:A9,0)),TRUE,(A2:A9=E1))*(B2:B9=E2)*(C2:C9))
```

[image]